# force DNN 5.6 to load ie7 WHEN using either IE8 or 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu, cross-browser, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 5.6 and my site has a problen with the DNN menu. It shows up fine in Chrome, IE7 and FF but its messed up in IE8-9.

I want to force IE-8-9 to run as IE7 when the site/pages are loaded.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Make sure to put that close to the opening `<head>` tag, to avoid further issues

Comment: does that go in my ASCX file?

Comment: You need to get that into the <head></head> department of the page. I don't know where that is set in DotNetNuke, since i'm not too familiar with it.

Comment: It worked, you just need to put that meta tag at the start of the skin file. thanks!

Comment: edit: this didnt work, i tried it on another machine and it doesnt force IE7 mode... any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if the machine where this happens injects something into the head? Like user-defined stylesheets etc. This `<meta>` tag won't always work, if it is not the first tag in the head section

Comment: You could also try with a full forced IE7 mode instead of Emulate and Fallback. For this try: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />` See here for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533876(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have added this to the advanced page headers, and DNN loads it in the head section of the page but it does not load as IE7

Comment: Fresh out of ideas then, this is the only way known to me to achieve this. You said "DNN loads it in the head section" but does it load this as **first** item in the `<head>`?

Comment: it does not load it as the first item in the <head> section.. it loads it at the end..